# Error loading cakephp 2 plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I installed a plugin in CakePHP from Upload, I loaded it into in app / Config / bootstrap.php. thus
`CakePlugin::load('Upload');` but I'm getting the error below, do I need to do anything else? CakePHP 2.0

> Error: Upload.UploadBehavior could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class UploadBehavior below in file: C: \ xampp \
>   htdocs \

This class already exists in the plugin!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Upload Plugin Github Page](https://github.com/Grafikart/CakePHP-Upload#usage):

> This plugin work as a behaviour for your model so you have to attach it to your model

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'thumb' => 'img/posts/:id1000/:id'
        )
    )
);
```